# Android Google IO 2014: How to implement Activity transition with fragments?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, transition

How to implement Android 5, Lollipop, [Activity Transitions](https://www.google.com/events/io/io14videos/29b8979c-3dbf-e311-b297-00155d5066d7) using fragments?

Comment: You don't at the moment, at least in terms of official framework support. In the "Material Science" Google I|O presentation today, Chet Haase and Adam Powell indicated that extending the new activity transitions stuff to fragments is being worked on. Basically, they tackled the harder problem (activities) first. Extending it to fragments will be done by the L release, and they could not say if anything might be available via a preview channel earlier.

Comment: @CommonsWare, now, Lollipop is out there - any news on this feature? I can't find anything

Comment: @MichałK: Sorry, I have not gone looking for this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The API is pretty similar to Activity Transitions, albeit limited in some ways due to the difference between starting an activity and a fragment transaction.

Here are the basics:

1. Use a common string when defining `android:transitionName` or `View.setTransitionName` on the views you intend to share between the fragments
2. When creating a fragment transaction, call: `FragmentTransaction.addSharedElement(View sharedElement, String name)` with the view you intend to share (and its transition name).
3. Specify the `Transition` that you want to be run on the fragment via: `Fragment.setSharedElementEnterTransition(Transition transition)`
4. If you want to run multiple transitions, use a `TransitionSet` to aggregate them.

Comment: do I need to enable the transition in the Activity Theme?
I tried this solution but it doesn't seem to work, could it be because 'm tring to animate a view inside a nested fragment?

Comment: I also have the transition in the Activity Theme enabled but the animation is not visible. Do you have a working example to share?

Comment: i have apply the transition between fragmentA containg list of item and FramgmentB is details now if list has single item my transition works fine but have multiple items in list it's not working